# Login page in sencha architect

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

Am stuck with the login page i followed the steps given in the below link and got almost but not able to login
http://docs.sencha.com/architect/2/#!/guide/views_forms_touch
In my json file i have Name, id, Mobile, etc., so i used Name for username and Mobile for the password, just for a change but am not able to login..
From the above link i found that field name in config is one which is referring(i guessed from the link since its mentioned "Change its name config to username") so i changed username field's name config to Name and password field's name config to Mobile but the result is loginfailed..I think from the code above it should display login is successful if username and password is correct..I just modified a little according to my json file that is Name in place of username and Mobile in place of password, yet the result is same(Login failed)..Am in dilemma what should i refer whether its name or id in config..For source i have posted my json file as text format and my architect folder in the forum http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthre...983#post952983
Can anyone pls check it and tel me..
Thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code displays login failed when the request to

```
http://csi01:888/SenchaService/Sencha.asmx/GetUserList
```

fails. As the very first step I would test it in the browser and check the inspectors network tab to see what request goes out and what fails there. It seems to me that your problem is not in the sencha code but something on the server side code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply zoltan magyar...Nw my doubt is that returned json value is correct so wen i refer the fields from the json value it should login but it doesn't..Then i want to clear whether its the name config is one which is referring the fields(from json values)